# Stream producer and consumer with asyncio gather python

Tags: python-3.x, queue, python-asyncio, asyncsocket

I wrote a script for a socket server that simply listens for incoming connections and processes the incoming data. The chosen architecture is the `asyncio.start_server` for the socket management and the `asyncio.Queues` for passing the data between the producer and consumer coroutines. The problem is that the `consume(q1)` function is executed only once (at the first script startup). Then it is not more executed. Is the line `run_until_complete(asyncio.gather())` wrong?

```
import asyncio
import functools

async def handle_readnwrite(reader, writer, q1): #Producer coroutine
    data = await reader.read(1024)
    message = data.decode()
    await writer.drain()
    await q1.put(message[3:20])
    await q1.put(None)
    writer.close() #Close the client socket

async def consume(q1): #Consumer coroutine
    while True:
        # wait for an item from the producer
        item = await q1.get()
        if item is None:
            logging.debug('None items') # the producer emits None to indicate that it is done
            break
        do_something(item)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
q1 = asyncio.Queue(loop=loop)
producer_coro = asyncio.start_server(functools.partial(handle_readnwrite, q1=q1), '0.0.0.0', 3000, loop=loop)
consumer_coro = consume(q1)
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(consumer_coro,producer_coro))

try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

loop.close()
```

Comment: Maybe the problem is that `handle_readnwrite` always enqueues `None`, which causes `consume` to break (and therefore finish the coroutine). How did you expect `consume` to process more than one message?

Comment: Thanks so much @user4815162342! It works fine now. The process <consume> should be running always.

Comment: I've now added the same explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

`handle_readnwrite` always enqueues the `None` terminator, which causes `consume` to break (and therefore finish the coroutine). If `consume` should continue running and process other messages, the `None` terminator must not be sent after each message.